# Quickbooks 2010 crashes when trying to register (or not register)

Tags: windows-10, crash, quickbooks

I've been running Quickbooks 2010 on Windows 10 for the last year with no problem. After this last Windows 10 update, however, I am no long able to open Quickbooks. It opens to the point where it asks me to register and then it crashes regardless whether I choose Register Now or Register Later. I have tried the following:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled QB with clean install, including using the Clean Install tool.
2. Repaired the installation
3. Re-registered QB in the registry using the reboot.bat tool in the QB folder.
4. Ran sfc /scannow -- no errors found

The problem is not the data file because I get the same response whether opening the data file or a sample data file. I confirmed this by installing QB2010 on my laptop and the program registered successfully and opened the data file with no problems.

The application event logs show these errors:

> An unexpected error has occured in "QuickBooks Pro 2010": Connection
>   Error:Invalid user ID or password
>
> An unexpected error has occured in "QuickBooks Pro 2010": Connection
>   String:CON=QBConnectionPool-Probe-QB_data_engine_20; ;DBF=C:\Users[my
>   username]\Documents[data
>   filename].QBW;ENG=QB_data_engine_20;DBN=df443c5d1bab473882f50ceca47a343a
>
> An unexpected error has occured in "QuickBooks Pro 2010":
>   DBConnPool::HandleConnectionError errorCode:-6069, dbCode:-103 from
>   file:'..\src\ConnPool.cpp' at line 1036 from
>   function:'DBMgr::DBConnPool::init'
>
> An unexpected error has occured in "QuickBooks Pro 2010": QuickBooks
>   has experienced a problem and must be shut down.
>
> Faulting application name: qbw32.exe, version: 20.0.4017.807, time
>   stamp: 0x510c5e5f Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   10.0.14393.187, time stamp: 0x57cf98b1 Exception code: 0xc000041d Fault offset: 0x000d96c2 Faulting process id: 0x3c04 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d216bdb77c11e8 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\QuickBooks 2010\qbw32.exe Faulting
>   module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   bc8ee4f4-5ce5-4b18-a9a6-04833222760f Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> An unexpected error has occured in "QuickBooks Pro 2010":
>   DBConnPool::HandleConnectionError errorCode:-6069, dbCode:-103 from
>   file:'..\src\ConnPool.cpp' at line 1036 from
>   function:'DBMgr::DBConnPool::init'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you apply all of the patches?  2010 has approx 9 major patches by now.  If you can get to **Get Updates** that should handle them all.

Comment: I did get in and apply the patches somehow by using the sample file but now that won't even load.

Comment: It's the registration component that crashes the program. I can open the file but I get a screen asking if I want to complete the registration or do it later. Regardless which option I choose, the next page tries to open but crashes.

Comment: I even tried removing every reference I could find to Quickbooks in the registry and then reinstalled. Still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a user with the same problem you are facing. Win 10, QB 10, same DLL. I actually came across this when looking for a solution, but couldn't find anything specific for it online. the only clue I had is that she said it did updates last night, and didn't work today.

I had to roll back the Windows 10 to the previous build and it worked. I used the registry to set the network adapters to metered connections so it wont load updates. Its not a permanent fix, but they are going to upgrade their QB pretty soon now that this happened.

Comment: I can't roll back to the last build -- I get a message that says the required files have been deleted. Go figure. :-(

Answer (score 0):

QuickBooks V2010 is now nearly 10 years out of date. A user above had to roll back Windows 10 to a prior version. So you are now at a point where you must upgrade QuickBooks to a newer version. Windows 10 keeps marching on.

FWIW here, I am a QuickBooks Pro Advisor and serve QB clients.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Intuit's side only supports 3 versions back?  At least for the Pro tier, not sure if the same applies to Enterprise.